# Can lower level intermediate cert declare SAN that broader than higher level cert?

Tags: tls, certificates

Suppose 1st level intermediate cert specifies `DNS=www.dev.com`

Can 2nd level intermediate cert which is signed by the 1st level specify `DNS=*.dev.com` or maybe `DNS=*.dev2.com`?

Does certificate level affect SAN in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a given setup -- it is working configuration. Subject Alternative Names are constrained through different means -- [Name Constraints](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.10) extension in CA certificate. If you do not use Name Constraints, you can use whatever name you want in any certificate.